# How can i get original method and uri of request when handling errors in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to handle all 404 errors with one page which shows method and uri of endpoint , that cause the error .

I'he made this controller .

```
 public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        ViewBag.Message = $"{Request.HttpMethod} {Request.Url} not supported";
        return View();
    }

}
```

And in Web.Config

```
 <system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace"  >
    <remove statusCode="404"/>
    <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

and view of error-page

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>@ViewBag.Message</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

But request is different , so i lost original url and method. How can i change it?

Comment: `Request.Url` or `Request.RawUrl`?

Comment: It does not matter because it's another Request object - that's my problem . Request.Url suits well , it shows right stuff , but not url that caused the error